# Zooming background photo after page is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been using this CSS technique to properly stretch a photo as a background - no matter what display size is:

```
html { 
background: url(/images/back.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

But now I want to pour some motion to my project. I've seen some sites use CSS transition to slowly zoom in background after document is loaded. Unfortunately, as I noticed it's done with img element and I want to stick with my recent technique. Maybe anybody has done something similar or have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use something like (-moz, -web)-transition: background-size 2s ease-in?

Comment: AFAIK you can only transition between numerical values, so an initial `background-size: 100%` is necessary instead of `cover`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only use CSS transitions between numerical values, so an initial `background-size: 100%` is necessary instead of `cover`.

```
html {
    background-image: url(/your/background/image/here.jpg);
    background-size: 100%; /* must be a numerical value to transition */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    transition: background-size 2s;
}
.trans {
    background-size: 120%;
}
```

Then add the `trans` class dynamically using JavaScript to make the magic happen.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Xd5hz/

Answer (score 0):

You should make a fiddle like this next time: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/aT64b/)

I'm not sure how you can get `cover` to go *a little bigger* - but here is the basics of how you can do something when the window loads. What tricks I would use would depend on how responsive you are going, and what the image is like.

### CSS

```
html { 
    background: url(http://placehold.it/1800x1800) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

### JS

```
// When the page is loaded... 
$(window).load( function() {
    // alert('the whole page is loaded');    
    // do stuff here...
});

// on click for example... (page loads too fast... )
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('html').animate({
        'background-size' : '120%'    
    });   
});
```